# Clipping element to width of other element

Tags: html, css

I've got a page that's supposed to display thumbnails of images with their file names underneath. Here's what I'm using at the moment:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" class="thumbContainer">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="preview4.jpg">
    <br>
    <span class="description">preview4.jpg</span>
</a>
```

**CSS**:

```
.description{
    width: 100%;
    height: 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}.thumbnail{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    max-height: 150px;
}.thumbContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

This works well enough, except that long file names expand their parent container, messing up the page layout. I'd like the shorter file names to remain centered the way they are now, but have names that are too long be clipped so they are no wider than the image in their container. The image width is unknown. Any ideas how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrz3/1/

**CSS:**

```
.thumbContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background:#333;
    max-width:154px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.thumbnail{
    display:block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    max-height: 150px;

}
.description{
    height: 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

Comment: This works the way you have it, except many of my thumbnails are much wider than that, and their exact width is unknown. Your code stops working when I take out the max-width.

Comment: You have to fix the width of container or description & overflow hidden property to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Give .thumbContainer a width equal to the width of the thumbnail images.

Also give .thumbContainer text-align:center

Answer (score 0):

try setting this to your description class..

```
position: relative;
```

and also set 'overflow:hidden or auto' to your thumbContainer class!

if this did'nt work....you can try giving min-width or margin:0 auto; to one of your classes..keep going!